# EditActionForIndexPath is displaying action for wrong row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using `editActionsForRow` method in the UITableViewDelegate. It's displaying the action for the wrong row.

I also used `trailingSwipeActionConfiguration` method but it didn't work.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
  let archiveAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Archive") { (action, customView, completion) in
    self.tableData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
  }
}
```

The action view shows up on the wrong row if I try to swipe two rows one by one.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but if you're using trailingSwipeActionConfigurationForRowAt, be sure to do this:  
`let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [archiveAction]);
return configuration`

Comment: Yeah, I did that but its something wrong with the tableView layout. If I reload the whole table it works fine.

Comment: Can you try setting the style to be .destructive instead of .normal in the UIContextualAction?

Comment: It works perfectly fine after .destructive thank you so much.!

Comment: Love to hear it!